# Unity applying weight to objects

Tags: unity, physics

Say i have two objects:
[image]

This is a rather big ball.

For scale here is my character next to the ball:
[image]

In the real world no single man would be able to push this nor would he be able to survive being crushed by it rolling down hill.

However My character is able to do both.

I am rather new to Unity and was wondering if there is something you can do about it? My initial thought was to add weight to objects but im not quite sure how?

Could anyone please explain how you go around these type of issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the Rigidbody's `mass` property.

[image]

Comment: How should you calculate the right mass?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen That's up to you, it's a giant ball of stone.  1000? 10000? What seems appropriate? What's a large enough value that it pushes your guy around, but doesn't break something else?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen It's irrelevant what unit you use. It can be grams, pounds, tons or solar-masses. It's just important that you keep your unit in mind and use the same unit to describe all masses and forces in your game.

Comment: @Philipp The [Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) defines it as kilograms by default. Not sure if density is ever a factor, but with 1 unit equaling 1 meter, it might be important to use units of mass in the same range. Just for consistency at least :)